# Chances at Going to a Math Grad School with 3.5 Math GPA

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a 3rd year at UChicago, and I'd really like to try and get a math PhD. Currently I have a 3.75 GPA (3.5 Math GPA—but if you remove the one B I got during CoVid that goes up to a 3.6). I've taken Real Analysis, Linear Algebra, Algebra, and Topology and got B+/A- in them. I expect to have taken a few more higher math electives (i.e. Measure Theory, ODEs, etc.) and 3 grad classes. I've also done an REU and some (3-5) reading programs in all sorts of fields with my specialty being in Geometry and Topology. I think I'll have decent recs.

What kinds of PhD programs could I realistically get into? Now I'd really like to go to a school like UMich, NYU, UChicago (again), Northwestern, CUNY, Brown, Cornell, CUNY etc. Would any (and if so which) be possible?

Also, I consider myself Agender. Would this hurt/help me in anyway in my application? I don't know any non-cis mathematicians so I figured I'd just ask that here.

Comment: The first part of the question is a Shopping question (or duplicate with what Brian posted), which is off-topic. And the second part is a totally different question that should be asked separately.

Comment: In a normal year you would be likely to get into most of those.  This year universities have less money, so nobody's predictions are useful.